# MS Access - Disable tagged controls based on combobox value

Tags: ms-access

I want to enable/disable all fields tagged as "hide me" based on the value I put in my combobox.

If comboxox is yes fields should be enabled, if no fields should be disabled.

Here'a a [working example](https://app.box.com/s/repq3d8bz80m5z2ejwqqtami5el6ci5b) to play with and here's my code, at the moment it doesn't work:

```
Private Sub myAction_AfterUpdate()

Dim frm As Form
Dim ctl As Control

Set frm = Forms!frmMyForm

    For Each ctl In frm.Controls

        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
            If ctl.Tag = "hideMe" Then
                If Me.myAction = yes Then
                    ctl.Enabled = True
                End If
            Else
                ctl.Enabled = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Code above and in the attachment are exactly the same. Make sure you don't put "hideMe" tag on `myAction` combo.

Comment: @Santosh Thank you. Yes, that was on purpose. The myAction combo is not tagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control tag had unwanted string (see image below) along with `hideMe` tag. 
 Below image has output of `Debug.Print ctl.Tag` on immediate window for quick reference.

Set the control tag as `hideMe` and run this code.

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub myAction_AfterUpdate()

Dim frm As Form
Dim ctl As Control

Set frm = Forms!frmMyForm

    For Each ctl In frm.Controls

        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then


            If ctl.Tag = "hideMe" Then
                If Me.myAction = "yes" Then
                    ctl.Enabled = True
                 Else
                     ctl.Enabled = False
                 End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**Code mistakenly copied along with hideMe**
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Santosh. This one does work. Do you have any idea, however, of what's wrong with my code? Trying to learn from my mistakes. :) I adapted my code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175021/disable-all-controls-in-details-section-of-a-ms-access-form

Comment: Yes, looks like accidentally you have copied entire code along with hideMe tags under control tag

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. ;p I've left the tag property of the "myAction" combobox empty and set the tag property of the other 5 field to "hideMe", like this. https://imgur.com/a/VKzAKK8 Isn't that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Go to textbox control=>open properties =>other tab=>set your cursor on `IME Sentence Mode` second last property => press tab=> cursor will move on to tag property=> copy the text and paste on notepad.

Comment: Got it now. D'oh. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You miss a *space* and to compare a **string**:

```
If ctl.Tag = "hide Me" Then
    If Me!myAction.Value = "Yes" Then
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code but this doesn't work . The items are tagged "hideMe", without spaces https://imgur.com/a/VKzAKK8 and the value of my action should be "yes" (or "no", or any other value the user wants to put in).

Comment: `Yes` is not a string but an unknown variable. `"Yes"` is a string.