# Enable / Disable Field based on Combo Selection

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I am new to Access and need assistance in enabling / disabling a field based on another field's selection.

I have a combo box called RegistrationType and if "Individual" is chosen I would like the "Business_Name" textbox to be disabled and if "Company" is chosen I would like it enabled.

Your help would be greatly appreciated :)

I am still having trouble getting this to work. I've tried everything.

So basically i just want to enable "Business Name", "ABN" & "Business Phone" when "Company" is chosen from "Registration Profile" and if "Individual" is chosen to disable them.
if anyone can help that would be amazing. I appreciate everyone trying.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuP0s.png)

Comment: it sounds more like disabling/enabling a form textbox or whatever based on which value the user selects in a combo-box.  In that case, disable the textbox ine the combo-box afterUpdate event.  Something like: if Me.cmbName = individual then Me.BusinessName.enabled = false.  for example see here for the case of multiple controls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275953/ms-access-disable-tagged-controls-based-on-combobox-value

Comment: Using VBA will cause all records to show textbox in the same state at same time. While this will certainly work it may be confusing to users. Conditional Formatting does not require VBA and enable/disable will apply dynamically for all records at same time.

Comment: Addendum, the possible confusion for users would occur if form is in continuous or datasheet view.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution :)

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    setRegistrationType
End Sub

Private Sub RegistrationType_AfterUpdate()
    setRegistrationType
End Sub

Private Sub setRegistrationType()
    Me![Business_Name].Enabled = RegistrationType & "" = "Business"
End Sub
```

This works well for Form-view but not for Continues forms.

Added the empty string in setRegistrationType to handle Null-values in Registration type.

Comment: Would also need this code in form Current event so that navigating records will allow the textbox to be available when appropriate. Use Conditional Formatting and no VBA is needed.

Comment: June7: yes you are right, added code for that.